# Any ideas on getting away from lengthy relative imports in cloud functions? Written in node.js and javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I was wondering if anyone here had some ideas or experience getting rid of long, hard-to-maintain relative imports inside of large node.js cloud functions projects. We’ve found that the approach which uses local NPM packages is very sub-optimal because of how quickly we tend to roll out and test new packages and functionality, and refactoring from JS to TS is impossible for us at the moment. We'd love to do it in the near future but are so slammed as it is currently :(
Basically what I’m trying to do in cloud functions is go from const {helperFunction} = require(‘../../../../../../helpers’)
to
const {helperFunction} = require(‘helpers’)
I have been unable to get babel or anything similar to that working in cloud functions. Intuitively I feel like there is an obvious solution to this beyond something like artifact registry or local NPM packages but i’m not seeing it! Any help would be greatly, greatly appreciated :)

Comment: In other words, one needs some method of setting up aliases for specific folders? For example an alias to (say) `utils` folders which may house `helpers` and the import becomes `require('@Utils/helpers');`.

Comment: @jfriend00 The OP did not comment on your answer.  I did.  I am trying to make sure the the OP gets accurate, actionable advice.  FYI Cloud Functions is a popular BaaS service hosted by Google Cloud Platform.  It's [very well documented](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs) and has a wrapper tool provided by [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions).  The question was tagged google-cloud-functions and firebase, so that's how you would know what was being discussed here.

Comment: @DougStevenson - I knew it was cloud-based.  Just trying to help by providing a  number of options for the OP to investigate.  I did mistakenly take your  comment as from the OP.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, I understand that.  Thank you.  I'm pointing out that some of them are simply not feasible or would require a workaround that depends on a dependency on undocumented implementation details.  That's why I suggested that you give them a try before recommending them.

Comment: @DougStevenson - If you know this environment well, what would you suggest?  On the otherhand, the OP has gone silent so maybe they're just gone and not engaging anyway.

Comment: @jfriend00 I don't have a suggestion yet because I haven't tried to do this.  I honestly don't know what would be both a stable and working solution supported by documentation.  When I get some free time, I'll give it a try.  It's time consuming because the round trip between code and deployment to an actual production environment is rather high.  Most devs prefer to use a local emulated environment, which is not necessarily close to the real thing with respect to changing or observing the way the runtime actually works.

Comment: Alright - thank you all for the comments and ideas! I've had a bunch of discussions yesterday and today with team members and someone from the startup program for GCP and I think we've come up with some information that might be useful to other people who are dealing with this. First, building out an entire API purely with cloud functions is relatively new, most people are still hesitant and tend to use something like cloud run + express. However, for us using GCF + API gateway is the fastest way to ship code.

Comment: Which I think is true for many small teams. Being able to quickly set up emulator environments is also hugely useful, as is the new versioning with Gen2 functions. However, as with most things, the most obvious solution is also the best one. Rebuild parts of the API in TS and deploy them one at a time as they get refactored. Lengthy process to be sure but the benefits greatly outway the costs of trying to stick doggedly to keeping it in Javascript. I feel like anyone just getting started building backends in cloud functions should be heavily pushed towards writing in TS from the start

Comment: Seems you've figured out the answer to your question. Could you please post it as an answer to contribute to the community.

Answer (score 1):

For CommonJS modules in general, you have several options.  I don't know the Google Cloud environment so you will have to decide which options seem appropriate to it.

The most attractive option to me is #5 as it's just a built-in search up the directory tree, designed specifically to look in the `node_modules` sub-directories of your parent directories.  If you can install the shared modules in that way, then nodejs should be able to find them as long as your directory hierarchy is retained by Google Cloud.

Options #3 and #4 are hacking on the loader which has its own risks, but does give you imlementation flexibility as you could implement your own prefix that looks in a particular spot.  But, it's hacking and may or may not work in the Google cloud environment.

Options #1 and #2 rely on environment variables and shared directories which may or may not be relevant in the Google cloud environment.

1. You can specify the environment variable NODE_PATH as a colon-delimited (or semi-colon on Windows) list of paths to search for modules.  Doc [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#loading-from-the-global-folders).
2. In addition, nodejs will search `$HOME/.node_modules` and `$HOME/.node_libraries` where `$HOME` is the user's home directory.
3. There is a package called `module-alias` [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) that is designed specifically to help you solve this.  You define module aliases in your package.json, import this one module and then you can use the directory aliases in your `require()` statements.
4. You can make your own pre-processor for resolving a module filename that is being loaded by require.  You cando this by monkey patching `Module._resolveFilename` to either modify the `filename` passed to it or to add additional search paths to the `options` argument.  This is the general concept that the `module-alias` package (mentioned in point #3 above) uses.
5. If the actual location of the helper module you want to load is in a `node_modules` directory somewhere above your current module directory on this volume, it can be found automatically as long as the require is just a filename as in `require("helpers")`.  An example in the doc [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#loading-from-node_modules-folders) describes this:

For example, if the file at `/home/ry/projects/foo.js` called `require('bar.js')`, then Node.js would look in the following locations, in this order:

```
/home/ry/projects/node_modules/bar.js
/home/ry/node_modules/bar.js
/home/node_modules/bar.js
/node_modules/bar.js
```

You can see how it automatically searches up the directory tree looking in each parent `node_modules` sub-directory all the way up to the root.  If you put these common, shared modules in your main project file's `node_modules` or in any directory above, then it will be found automatically.  This might be the simplest way to do things as it's just a directory structuring and removing of all the `../../` stuff you have in the paths.  Clearly these common, shared modules are already located somewhere common - you just need to make sure they're in this search hierarchy so they can be found automatically.

Note this info is for CommonJS modules and may be different for ESM modules.

Comment: 1, 2, and 5 will not work in Cloud Functions because 1) you don't have the ability to set environment vars (at least not easily), 2) you don't have a documented guarantee what $HOME is ahead of time and you can't directly control its contents, and 3) you don't have control over what goes into node_modules after the system runs npm install for you. module-alias has a chance of working.  Note that Cloud Functions deployments are essentially docker images that are built for you based on code you provide and upload via CLI. I suggest first trying each of these before giving them as options here.

Comment: @DougStevenson - #5 has nothing to do with environment variables.  It's purely a search up the source tree of node_modules directories up the parent tree as a generic NPM install would do.  It is designed exactly for this type of problem (using modules, parents have loaded as a dependency).  If Google breaks all of this structure, then they must offer their own solution as there has to be a way to find things in parent directories.  I don't know Google Cloud Services at all - just trying to offer possible suggestions.

Comment: @DougStevenson - I've made the preamble to my answer more Google Cloud relevant (within the limits of my knowledge).